# Error while building fat jar for deploying my jar to remote Cluster

Tags: build.gradle, apache-storm

I have set up a single node cluster and trying to deploy my sample topology to it .

I believe to deploy my topology to cluster I have to submit the jar with all dependencies to the Cluster .

For that I created a sample project and added a simple topology to it .

While generating the fat jar using gradle I am seeing this error

gradle fatjar gives below error

```
Could not expand ZIP '/Users/agarg/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-
2.1/org.apache.storm/storm-
core/0.9.5/d2bf27db853347dcf66990b4514db20a7897303e/storm-core-0.9.5.jar'.

 Could not copy zip entry /Users/agarg/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files- 
 2.1/org.apache.storm/storm-  
 core/0.9.5/d2bf27db853347dcf66990b4514db20a7897303e/storm-core-  
 0.9.5.jar!META-INF/license/LICENSE.base64.txt to  '/Users/agarg/Documents/notificationRepo/sample/build/tmp/expandedArchives/storm-
core-0.9.5.jar_366us3312tpl54tci2fld83fij/META-INF/license/LICENSE.base64.txt'.
```

Here is my build.gradle file fo reference :

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'clj-stacktrace' , name: 'clj-stacktrace',version: cljStackTrace
    compile group: 'org.apache.storm' , name: 'storm-core',version: stormVersion
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
 manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
      'Implementation-Version': version,
      'Main-Class': 'storm.topology.ExclamationTopology'
}
baseName = project.name + '-all'
from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }     }
with jar
```

}

```
buildscript {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
```

}
   }

Can nyone help me what is going wrong here ???

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with gradle, however, you do not need to include "storm-core" or transitive dependencies in your fat jar. It is sufficient if your far jar contains Spout and Bolt classes (and maybe some 3rd party libraries you are using that are not part of Storm)

Comment: Thanks Matthias . I managed to find a workaround for this. Now , I am able to submit my topology to remote cluster . But still topology is not getting started due to this :

java.lang.RuntimeException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar.

Do u have idea how to resolve this . My guess is I will have to stop sending the jar which has default.yml file in it similar to what u mentioned here

Comment: Yes. The jar must not contain `defaults.yaml` file. You should remove/exclude storm dependencies for building the fat jar.